# What is the correct way to SSH into a AWS Windows 10 machine from the Windows 10 Command Line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line, windows-10

I have been working on SSHing into an Ubuntu, AWS Linux 2, and AWS Windows servers. Though I am having trouble with Windows effort in the Windows Command Line. I know SSH should work on Windows 10 and I prefer not to involve PuTTY.

Q) What am I missing from my samples below that would help SSH from my Windows Command Line into a AWS Windows 10 Server?

- Linux-2: `ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-999-99-999-9.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ ec2-user@99.999.999.99`

  - Format: `ssh -i /path/XYZ.pem (PEM Key with path) ec2-user @(User ID for Linux 2) IP 4 Address`
- Ubuntu: `ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ubuntu@ec2-99-999-999-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ ubuntu@99.999.999.99`

  - Format: `ssh -i /path/XYZ.pem (PEM Key with path) Ubuntu @(User ID for Ubuntu) IP 4 Address`

I believe my problem lies with my default User ID for Windows (`Administrator@99.999.999.99`), but I am not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "having trouble"? Are you receiving an error message? Is there an SSH server process running on the Server? As a test, try to SSH _from_ the Server to itself (to `localhost`) to avoid any potential networking problems, just to see if the command syntax seems correct

Comment: It would time out on me.

I did manage to have some success by following the steps listed in here: 
-https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Use-SSH-Client-and-Server-on-Windows-10-1470/

I did have to get into my AWS Windows 2019 AMI with RDP and download and install SSH server, start SSHD and set it to Automatic, and confirm the Port 22 rules on the Get-NetFirewallRule. 

Once all this was configured I could SSH with the format included above. Though I would be interested in a method that did not involve PuTTY or the RDP intro step.

Regards,

J-CHS

Comment: You could create a User Data script that runs when the instance first boots. This script could install and configure the SSHD so that it is available. Or, you cold create an [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) script that can install and configure SSHD on a system, and trigger the Run Command on new instances.

Comment: This is extraordinarily helpful! I am definitely going to look into these options and try to use these User Data Scripts or AWS System Manager Run to configure the AWS AMI Instance to be formatted to my likeing. Thanks so much for giving me the pointers!